# Custom SSO ValveBase configuration in jBoss EAP 6.2 (migrating from 4.2)

Tags: jboss, migration, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6, jboss-4.2.x

I am migrating from jBoss EAP 4.2 to 6.2 and stuck at migration of SSO simulator valve implementation.

In jBoss EAP 4.2, I have config(in server.xml) like this to simulate/push SSO and other properties in request header for localhost only.

```
    <Valve className="com.xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz.SSOSimulatorValve" simFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/lib/ssosim.properties" />
```

How should i migrate/configure this in jBoss EAP 6.2?

Comment: Check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to define the SSO Simulator valve in jBoss EAP 6.x using following in jboss-web.xml

```
<valve>
    <class-name>x.y.z.SSOSimulatorValve</class-name>
    <param>
        <param-name>propFile</param-name>
        <param-value>${jboss.server.base.dir}\lib\ssoSimulatorProperties.properties
        </param-value>
    </param>
</valve>
```